# Using Java 7 update 45 but getting List is not generic error

Tags: list, arraylist

I have the following code

```
List<Double> array = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

This won't compile however because I'm getting an error on List which says "The type list is not generic; it cannot be parameterised with arguments.

I am using Java 7 update 45 and my complile path in eclipse to is JavaSE-1.7 so I thought this should be possible after JDK 5 , does anyone have any suggestions what might be going wrong? My imports are as follows...

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Comment: did you do `import java.util.List;`?

Comment: yes I did so im not sure whats going on....

Comment: can you show all your imports?

Comment: I've updated as above

Comment: you do `import java.awt.List;`, but should be `import java.util.List;`

Comment: Thanks that worked I still dont completely understand the difference between awt and util packages if you post this as an answer I can give you a tick so you can gain some reputation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `import java.util.List;` instead of `import java.awt.List;`. The former one is generic list, the latter one is display element.

[java.awt.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) - The List component presents the user with a scrolling list of text items.

[java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) - An ordered collection (also known as a sequence).